# Updating database tables when values are missing

Tags: sql, sybase, sql-update

I have two tables :

*Bill :*

```
create table Bill(
               BillDate datetime,
               Amount decimal(10,2) ,
               BillCurrency varchar(3) ,
               ReportingCurrency decimal(10,2))
```

*FxRate :*

```
create table FxRate( 
               RateDate datetime,
               SourceCurrency varchar(3),
               TargetCurrency varchar(3),
               ExchangeRate decimal(15,4))
```

This is what I want to do :

I want to update my Bill table as

```
update Bill 
set ReportingCurrency = FxRate.ExchangeRate * Bill.Amount
from FxRate
where FxRate.RateDate = Bill.BillDate
```

In this update all the rows which have an entry for that particular date will get the new reportingcurrency data. Since Bill table can have multiple rows eligible for the update , I have the following problem :

For the rows where there was no entry in FxRate table (for that date), the ReportingCurrency becomes NULL. I want to go back to the `nearest <= RateDate` and pick up the exchange rate.Is that possible using modifications in the same update statement or some other efficient method? (I want to avoid a cursor).

Comment: D'oh. Corrected a stupid mistake in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with a subquery. Hopefully my example below will work unmodified (and be error free!) The only note is you need to substitute your reporting (base) currency for my assumed 'USD'.

```
UPDATE Bill SET ReportingCurrency = (Bill.Amount * 
  (SELECT TOP 1 FxRate.ExchangeRate FROM FxRate
   WHERE FxRate.SourceCurrency = Bill.BillCurrency
   AND FxRate.TargetCurrency = 'USD'
   AND FxRate.RateDate <= Bill.BillDate
   ORDER BY FxRate.RateDate DESC))
```

Hope this helps. EDIT - Added ORDER BY Clause

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible - as a SELECT this would be:

```
SELECT
  b.BillDate,
  r.RateDate,
  r.ExchangeRate
FROM
  Bill b
  LEFT JOIN FxRate r ON r.RateDate = (
    SELECT MAX(RateDate) FROM FxRate WHERE RateDate <= b.BillDate
  )
```

Therefore, as an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE
  Bill
SET
  ReportingCurrency = r.ExchangeRate * b.Amount
FROM
  Bill b
  LEFT JOIN FxRate r ON r.RateDate = (
    SELECT MAX(RateDate) FROM FxRate WHERE RateDate <= b.BillDate
  )
```

The solution makes these assumptions:

- there is never more than one `FxRate` record for any given day
- there is an `FxRate` record that predates all `Bill` records

If these assumptions are not applicable, the query must be accommodated.

Also note that this is SQL Server syntax. It's possible that Sybase is a little different.

---

Since a commenter showed interest in a general "nearest date" solution:

```
UPDATE
  Bill
SET
  ReportingCurrency = r.ExchangeRate * b.Amount
FROM
  Bill b
  LEFT JOIN FxRate r ON r.RateDate = (
    SELECT TOP 1 RateDate 
    FROM         FxRate
    ORDER BY     ABS(DATEDIFF(d, RateDate, b.BillDate)), RateDate
  )
```

This would be quite slow, though. Alternative:

```
UPDATE
  Bill
SET
  ReportingCurrency = CASE 
                      WHEN DATEDIFF(d, r1.RateDate, b.BillDate) <= DATEDIFF(d, b.BillDate, r2.RateDate)
                      THEN r1.ExchangeRate
                      ELSE COALESCE(r2.ExchangeRate, r1.ExchangeRate)
                      END * b.Amount
FROM
  Bill b
  LEFT JOIN FxRate r1 ON r1.RateDate = (
    SELECT MAX(RateDate) FROM FxRate WHERE RateDate <= b.BillDate
  )
  LEFT JOIN FxRate r2 ON r2.RateDate = (
    SELECT MIN(RateDate) FROM FxRate WHERE RateDate >= b.BillDate
  )
```

Comment: What if the ->nearest<- RateDate would be > BillDate? I know that he didn't ask for that, just out of curiosity.

Comment: The OP was asking for the "nearest <= RateDate".

Comment: I know. As I said just out of curiosity, how would you solv this?